# Lost game & don't know what I used when I signed up

Tags: pokemon-go

My kid deleted the game & I can't remember if I used a google account or trainer club to log in.  I've tried both but still can't get the game with progress back.  Is there any way to tell which one was used?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell is to log in with every account you know you could have used. With GMail you could use the [google website](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?utm_source=OGB&pli=1) to check which apps you allowed to access your info. If Pokémon Go is in there you most likely have an account there. (If not you should check it anyway. It's just quicker, if you find a google account with Go having access.)

Comment: I don't think that Go uses Google Play Games (if you're on Android). 

My game is working fine, I log in with my main Gmail account but in this list in your link, the game doesn't appear.

Comment: It did earlier. I deleted mine, too, and it works fine. The rest of the answer still stands, though.